# gzip many files one by one

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, gzip

I have 100 files, n1.txt, n2.txt,… and I want to gzip each of them, but not in one file – finally I'd like to have 100 `n*.txt.gz` files.

How can I do that in Linux with Bash?

Comment: Did you check the man pages?  They are great when you need to get help on the allowed syntax of a command.

Comment: Note that gzip does not allow compressing multiple files into one archive, because it's not an archive format (only a compression format). For that, you need to use tar, and compress the resulting tar archive with gzip.

Answer (score 8):

To compress all files, you can use:

```
gzip n*.txt
```

The `n*.txt` will expand to all file names as arguments for `gzip`.

Answer (score 2):

While hymie's answer perfectly covers the solution, I would like to offer an alternative which may be a bit more flexible as it allows you to use the `find` command first to check if your `regex` matches what you want and only then `gzip` the files.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec gzip {} \;
```

This searches from your current working directory for all files ending in `.txt` and `gzip`'s them one by one.

On `gzip` you may want to pass:
`-v` verbose
`-k` keep the original file
`-9` zip level (9 most compressed, 6 default)

Alternatively you may want to use `pigz` which is present in most distros and which is a parallel drop-in for `gzip`.

```
# parallel gzips all text files in the subfolders below command
find . -name "*.txt" -exec pigz -v9 {} \;
```

[Taken from here.](https://wasteofserver.com/linux-find-and-gzip-a-bunch-of-files/)